# @EJB not injected to JAX-RS

Tags: ejb, jax-rs

I have `@LocalBean`s and JAX-RS resources in different packages in a single ear.

And I also have a ServletFilter filtering before those resources.

I found that `@EJB` works for the ServletFilter but not for those resources.

```java
@Stateless
@LocalBean
class MyBean { // in ejb jar
}

@WebFilter(urlPatterns = {"/*"})
class MyFilter implements Filter { // in the same war
    @EJB MyBean myBean; // not null
}

@ApplicationPath("/")
class MyApplication extends Application { // in the same war
}

@Path("/my")
class MyResource { // in the same war
    @EJB MyBean myBean; // null
}
```

No logs special, just an NPE in MyResource's method.
Can anybody help me?

UPDATE -----------------------------------------------

Making those resource classes as `@Stateless` do works.

But I just curious that those ejb-jar and web-war are assembled into a single ear.

And then the web-war is a web component, isn't it?

UPDATE2 ------------------------------------------------------

Oh, I'm sorry. There is also `MyApplication` that makes MyResource as a JAX-RS resource.

When I deploy the `ear` GF detect it as an 'Enterprise Application'.

UPDATE3 ---------------------------------------------------------------

Here comes my application.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<application xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/application_6.xsd" version="6">
  <display-name>sngp-v0-ear</display-name>
  <module> <!-- EJBs are here -->
    <ejb>sngp-v0-beans-1.0-alpha-1-SNAPSHOT.jar</ejb>
  </module>
  <module>
    <web> <!-- JAX-RS are here -->
      <web-uri>sngp-v0-mobile-resources-1.0-alpha-1-SNAPSHOT.war</web-uri>
      <context-root>/sngp-v0-mobile-resources</context-root>
   </web>
  </module>
  <library-directory>lib</library-directory>
</application>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`MyResource` class isn't either a web component or an enterprise bean, but you are trying to inject an EJB into it. EJB injection is guaranteed to work only when the client is either a web component or another enterprise bean.

Try making `MyResource` `@Stateless`.

Have a look at this Java EE 6 [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gipjf.html) regarding `EJB` injection. If you are using NetBeans, I have also found useful using the built-in wizard for creating RESTFul web services. Check out this [link](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/websvc/rest.html) in case.

Comment: It works!!! But I DO remember it worked without `@Stateless` at least in this morning. That's what makes me crazy. Can you please tell me why `@Stateless` needed with JSX-RS resource classes?

Comment: It's difficult to tell you why it was working before, without seeing the code. The reason why it works with Stateless is well explained in the linked Java EE 6 tutorial. Essentially, with Stateless you are making your EJB client (MyResource) a class whose lifecycle is managed by the container.

Comment: As per your edit: being in a war or in a ear doesn't make much difference in this context. What is relevant is the nature of the client class of your injected EJB (MyResource in this case). If MyResource isn't marked as a WebService or a Servlet or an Enterprise Bean, then the container isn't managing its lifecycle and the EJB injection may fail.

Comment: I must admit that I'm not sure that it worked before or not. Sorry. I think I'm getting crazy.